# How do I mix comparison operators with a joins query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do something like this:

```
Aoy.joins(:member).where(season_year: session[:season_year], members: {"debut_date.year <= ?", session[:season_year]} ).order(total_points: :desc).each_with_index do |aoy, i|
```

"Only show Aoy entries of members that have debuted in the same year or previous to the season_year session"

1. How do I mix comparisons and with join statement?
2. How do I extract "year" from debut_date (debut_date.year) within the .where statement, is that possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the query in SQL instead of ActiveRecord for handling this use case. For extracting year from a date field, you can use SQL [YEAR](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-get-the-year-from-a-date-in-t-sql/) method:

```
Aoy.joins(:member)
   .where(season_year: session[:season_year])
   .where("YEAR(members.debut_date) <= ?", session[:season_year])
   .order(total_points: :desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `YEAR()` of SQL [ref](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp)

```rb
Aoy.joins(:members)
   .where(season_year: session[:season_year])
   .where("YEAR(debut_date) <= ?", session[:season_year])
   .order(total_points: :desc)
```